# Select events of a product in rows for each month and put concatenate in another table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a Biguery table like this:

| Product | Date | Event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-03-08 | M |
| A | 2022-03-25 | P |
| A | 2022-02-03 | S |
| B | 2022-02-20 | Q |
| B | 2022-03-10 | R |

Based on current date (2022-03-29), I need to insert in another Bigquery table in this format:

| Product | Month-0 | Month-1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | M;P | S |
| B | R | Q |

I appreciate if you can help me.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

using pivot and string_agg will do this aggregation

```
With tbl as
(SELECT "A" Product , date "2022-03-08" date, "M" event
Union ALL SELECT "A", "2022-03-25", "P"
Union ALL SELECT "A", "2022-02-03", "S"
Union ALL SELECT "B", "2022-02-20", "Q"
Union ALL SELECT "B", "2022-03-10", "R"
)

SELECT *, 
from 
(SELECT Product,event, date_diff(current_date(),date,month) as diff
from tbl)
PIVOT(string_agg(event,";") month FOR diff IN (0,1,2)  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
execute immediate (select '''
select * from your_table
pivot(string_agg(event,";") month for date_diff(current_date(),date,month) in (''' || string_agg('' || value) || '''))
'''
from (
  select max(date_diff(current_date(),date,month)) max_diff from your_table
), unnest(generate_array(0, max_diff)) value
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: good point: The amount of possible month columns is not known. Your query generates for each month in the past a column.

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: yes, I have tried. If the number of months is known, I think my solution is good; if the number is unknown, yours is better. Please take it as a compliment and my esteem.

Comment: sorry, Samuel for confusion. This kind of question ("have you tried?") - usually goes to OP (the person who asked the question) :o)